# How is the "N-in-one" or "pill" button effect effected?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

I want to use what I think is called the "pill" button that can be seen here: 
http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ (the "Choice 1 | Choice 2 | Choice 3" widget)

Here's a screen shot:

[image]

What html and/or css and/or jquery is required to achieve that look? I want to be able to highlight 0..all of the buttons (based on which ones are applicable at the time/in the current state).

Comment: it's jquery ui radio inputs http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio

Comment: [download](http://jqueryui.com/download) -> Components -> Widgets -> ☑ Button -> [Download]

Comment: View the source of an example that you like

Comment: And theme on your screenshot is **Excite Bike**

Comment: @Shaddow: I know; I'm kind of excited by Excite-Bike (not in a weird way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the information about "buttonset" [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/button/). In short, you create a container with several radio buttons in it, and apply `buttonset` to the container, and you will get a radio control that's styled as jQuery UI buttons.

Comment: Oh, they're radio buttons; that's not going to work, then. I need more than one to potentially be enabled. IOW, they are options, of which 0..all can be available; I want to indicate their availableness by appearance, but not have only one be the "choice." I guess their choice of wording, using "choice" should have been a tipoff.

Comment: @ClayShannon It probably works for checkboxes too. UPDATE: [Ta-da!](http://codepen.io/millimoose/pen/xweJu)